# Invalid token '=>' in class, struct, or interface member declaration in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015. Is there a problem in the code? Please guide. I'm also still a beginner in C#.

```cs
public partial class Root : Form
{
    private BindingList<Product> list = null;
    private BindingSource bindingSource = null;

    public Root() => InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: You need to check the c# version of the project. Expression bodied members (`public Root() => InitializeComponent();`) was introduced in c# 6. If the c# version is lower than 6, you can't use expression bodied members.

Comment: "I'm using Visual Studio 2015" - then you'll be using a very old version of C#. I strongly recommend that you upgrade to VS 2022.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: More than that, this is an expression-bodied *constructor*, and that was introduced in C# 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an old version of C# that comes with Visual Studio 2015. If you can, you should upgrade to Visual Studio 2022, so that you can use language features like [expression bodied constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#constructors).

If you cannot or do not want to upgrade to the latest Visual Studio and C# versions, then the easy fix is to change the constructor like this:

```cs
public partial class Root : Form
{
    //...

    public Root()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

As Jon Skeet noted, expression-bodied constructors are only supported in C# 7.0 and higher.

Comment: Your answer went perfectly